# Why such a strong action by a moderator by deleting a meta question thread post for being courteous?

Tags: discussion, meta

I just had a response in a [question thread](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/563/why-not-include-a-more-organized-community-wiki-process/572#572) deleted because I said "Thanks" for a well considered response.  The issue I am discussing regarding a knowledge wiki for basic, constantly repeated answers is appropriate. Having the post deleted is like a slap down.  Very rude!  The comment by the moderator is appropriate, the act of deleting the entire comment is a real turn-off/put down to someone new trying to participate on the site.

Answer (score 2):

It has been deleted because it is not an answer to your own question; it could be a different question, but it's not an answer to your own question. The fact you started with "Thanks kiamlaluno," made it seems as you were replying to me. In your "answer" you then say, "Please let me know if you think such a resource makes sense here at Drupal Answers." which makes it another question altogether, as you are implicitly asking "Do you think such a resource makes sense here at Drupal Answers?"

SE sites are not forums, and answers are not threads; this means there isn't a continuous feedback between who asks a question, and who replies.
In a forum, a user would wrote a post, somebody else could ask a question to which the OP replies, then the other user could answer to the question asked in the post, the OP could say the other user is still not understanding what he is asking, etc. on SE sites, including meta sites, you ask a question, and you get an answer; if there is something you don't understand in an answer, you can ask that in a comment for the answer, but if the exchange of comments become too long, you get the suggestion to continue the discussion on a chat room appositely created, as comments are not thought for discussion.

Comment: I appreciate your response. My follow up expands on the ?, addressing how the site can be used or maybe improved.  Your answer was informative but immediately leads me to further clarifications & expansion ?s.  In this way it is similar to a forum discussion.  I believe there should be accommodation for following up & these comment boxes are too limited in size & features to do it in.  I came to this site because of the high response rate to ?s, & like helping newcomers when I can.  The ? & followup is on topic! Let's not be intolerant bureaucrats. I'm out of space in the box.

Comment: If you have any follow up, you should report that in a new question. Stack Exchange sites are Q&A sites, not discussion web sites; this means that what is allowed, or not, is more restrictive than what a forum site would allow. It's not a matter of being bureaucrats; it's just a matter of defining what is welcome, and what is not welcome. On Stack Exchange sites, it is already defined what is welcome.